# Class can't be used as parameter for MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

I'm rewriting a current working POS system that was created in C# using the .NET Framework. When trying to build the project the compiler returns error CS0311 saying that the type of the parameter given can't be used.

I've researched the used classes and everything it needs according to the .NET documentation is defined in the class so I have no clue why it doesn't work.

The code used in EfDbContext.cs:

```
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.Conventions;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Dal.Migrations;
using Dal.Model;

namespace Dal
{
    public class EfDbContext : DbContext
    {
        private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public EfDbContext()
          : base(Settings.ConnectionString ?? "")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<EfDbContext>((IDatabaseInitializer<EfDbContext>) new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<EfDbContext, Configuration>());
            EfDbContext.logger.Debug("Database entity context initialized");
        }

        public DbSet<Member> Members { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Role> Roles { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TaxCategory> TaxCategories { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Ticket> Tickets { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TicketLine> TicketLines { get; set; }

        public DbSet<MemberCard> MemberCards { get; set; }

        public DbSet<CheckoutSheet> CheckoutSheets { get; set; }

        public DbSet<Transaction> Transactions { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>().HasMany<TicketLine>((Expression<Func<Ticket, ICollection<TicketLine>>>)(p => p.TicketLines)).WithRequired().WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Ticket>().HasMany<Transaction>((Expression<Func<Ticket, ICollection<Transaction>>>)(p => p.Transactions)).WithOptional((Expression<Func<Transaction, Ticket>>)(m => m.Ticket)).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Member>().HasMany<MemberCard>((Expression<Func<Member, ICollection<MemberCard>>>)(p => p.MemberCards)).WithRequired((Expression<Func<MemberCard, Member>>)(m => m.Member));
            modelBuilder.Entity<CheckoutSheet>().HasMany<Ticket>((Expression<Func<CheckoutSheet, ICollection<Ticket>>>)(p => p.Tickets)).WithOptional((Expression<Func<Ticket, CheckoutSheet>>)(m => m.CheckoutSheet)).WillCascadeOnDelete(true);
        }

        public override int SaveChanges()
        {
            try
            {
                return base.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbEntityValidationException ex)
            {
                throw new FormattedDbEntityValidationException(ex);
            }
        }

        ~EfDbContext()
        {
            EfDbContext.logger.Debug("Database entity context destroyed");
        }
    }
}
```

Code used in Configuration.cs:

```
using NLog;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

namespace Dal.Migrations
{
    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<DbContext>
    {
        private static readonly Logger logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        public Configuration()
        {
            this.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
            this.AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
            this.ContextKey = "POS.Dal.EfDbContext";
        }

        protected override void Seed(DbContext context)
        {
            Configuration.logger.Info("Database migration completed");
        }
    }
}
```

[CS0311 error returned by compiler][1]

```
Error   CS0311  
The type 'Dal.Migrations.Configuration' cannot be used as type parameter 'TMigrationsConfiguration' in the generic type or method 'MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration>'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Dal.Migrations.Configuration' to 'System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrationsConfiguration<Dal.EfDbContext>'.    
Dal 2   
D:\lagae\Documents\Point Of Sale\POS\Dal    
D:\lagae\Documents\Point Of Sale\POS\Dal\EfDbContext.cs 
Line 20 
Column 134
```

Does somebody see what I did wrong?

Kind Regards,

Jerlag_01

Comment: Please don't paste images of anything, unless there is something that cant be shown in text

Comment: So on which line does this exception happen?

Comment: In the EfDbContext.cs file, Line 20 at DatabaseInitializer at the end where I say it needs to call the configuration.cs file